# Angular ui-router sends form data to url after submit

Tags: angularjs, forms, angular-ui-router, submit

Need help please.
I work with Angular ui-router.
I have a form on my page, with 3 simple fields: name, tel and email.
When I submit the form, all data from fields go to url as parameters.
And the whole state is being updated. What I don't want.

So before submit my URL looks like this: `sweetLab/#/course/he`

after submit: `sweetLab/?name=aaaaaa&tel=342432&email=aaaaa%40aaa.com#/course/he`
I use ajax request to php file through the service

the form:

```
<form action="" name="userForm" ng-controller="signupCtrl" novalidate>
<h3>{{::content.form.title}}</h3>
<div class="inputWrap" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine }">
    <input required ng-maxlength="30" ng-minlength="2" type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name" placeholder="{{::content.form.name}}">

</div>
<div class="inputWrap" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.tel.$invalid && !userForm.tel.$pristine }">
    <input type="tel" required ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*-?[0-9]*-?[0-9]*$/" name="tel" ng-model="user.tel" placeholder="{{::content.form.tel}}" >

</div>
<div class="inputWrap" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine }">
    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" ng-pattern="/^[a-z]+[a-z0-9._]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z.]{2,5}$/" placeholder="{{::content.form.email}}">

</div>
<button ng-click="save(userForm.$valid)" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid"></button>
```

the Controller:

```
 $scope.save = function(isValid){
    if(isValid){
        console.log($scope.user);
        data.addUser($scope.user);
    }
    else{
        console.log('not valid');
    }
}
```

service:

```
this.addUser = function (user) {
        return $http.post('bin/User.php?action=addUser', user)
            .success(function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                return res;
            })
            .error(function () {
                return 'error';
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I found a problem.
This wasn't a problem of ui router.
The only thing I was missing is `type="button"` on my button tag